# How to set framework path for TheOs?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak

I want to use SpringBoardservice.Framework but TheOs seems to be unknown of it.who can help me???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use the SpringBoardServices.framework you have to dump it yourself using either class-dump or **class-dump-z** (Preferred) class-dump-z can be installed from Cydia by adding the repo:

`ininjas.com/repo/`

Then you would have to install **Mobile Terminal** (From Cydia) and run

class-dump-z -H /System/Library/Frameworks/SomeFramework/SomeFrameworkBinary -O /var/mobile/somefolder

To get the headers in var/mobile/somefolder

Anyways you could always use **rpetrich's dumped headers** (Which I personally as  a Cydia dev myself use) Here's the link https://github.com/rpetrich/iphoneheaders

Then you would have to put all the framework header folders in /var/theos/include (Wherever your theos folder is, in my case on my device therefore var/theos/include)

After that you have to add the line

```
#import <SomeFramework/SomeFramework.h>
```

in your tweak.xm / tweak.mm. Happy coding!

Comment: yes ,what you say is very helpful to me.but do you notice that springboard is not a framework,in fact it is a app!!So i cant add it。。。。。。

Comment: You asked for "SpringBoardServices" which is NOT an app. You CAN dump headers from the binary located in the SpringBoard.app and creat a folder called SpringBoard with the headers in it to make tweaks for the SpringBoard

Comment: Do you put all the folders in your iPhone? or in your Mac?